# Ubuntu 13.10 Server + MAAS : Pb to import boot images

Tags: 13.10, maas

Before I try to install an Ubuntu MAAS server on a real machines and add 1 or 2 nodes, I wanted to test the (Ubuntu 13.10 + MAAS + Juju + OpenStack) solution with 2-3 VMware virtual machines (under Windows 7 Pro 64-Bit).

So I created a small VMWare VM (2 processors/2GB memory/60GB hard disk) and installed the Ubuntu MAAS server (following the instructions on http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/install.html#import-the-boot-images ; everything except the DHCP/DNS stuff)). When connecting to the web interface, I followed the instructions:

1. I created the superuser;
2. I clicked on the "Import Boot Images" of the cluster controller.

Nothing happened. So I logged on the Ubuntu server and ran the command `maas-cli maas node-groups import-boot-images`. Nothing happened (except a message saying that it started).

By nothing happened, I mean that several hours later, I still have the web interface telling me that there are no boot images. And no idea what happened because I have no idea where I could eventually find a log file/message.

From a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 Server + MAAS install, I execute the following commands as specified in the manual:

```
$ sudo maas createsuperuser
$ maas-cli login maas http:///MAAS/api/1.0 4a7ehDMkZWStdmSCmX:KaYPpAuL5wWJmJtamr:A5JLyz8WLnwaHcPKGzJxqJ73mqYe5tns
You are now logged in to the MAAS server at ... blablabla...
$ maas-cli maas node-groups import-boot-images
Import of boot images started on all cluster controllers
$ ps -ae | grep maas
```

And there is nothing to see there... The MAAS page on the server still claims that there are no boot images imported.

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo maas-import-pxe-files` from the command line on the MaaS server? Does it just sit there? Return the prompt? Give some error?

Comment: I'm still on the issue but still no progress. From a fresh Ubuntu 13.10 Server + MAAS install, I execute the following commands as specified in the manual: aargh... I can't have a newline in the comment section :-) Let's start again at the bottom of the page :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `/var/log/maas/celery.log` to make sure the import task starts and does not immediately stop with an error of some kind. From my experience, `import-boot-images` won't succeed if the MAAS Cluster Controller does not have access to the Internet, or if the DHCP/DNS configuration on the VM network is not properly configured.

Once you see no errors after running `maas-cli maas node-groups import-boot-images` in the celery.log file, you can check with `ps -ae | grep maas` to see - the import process should be running.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still working on this. I am currently trying to figure maas out, and it's a pain in the ass.

To see if the download is still working, check the output of:

```
ps -ae | grep maas
```

I got:

```
2608 ?        00:01:36 maas-import-eph
```

What this is doing is pulling from `maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral` These images are about 300M and there are a couple of them for it to download.

Not sure how many people have been having success setting this up completely.